# SQL: Cast Not working in SubString

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

We have a string field for date of birth and now we have to convert it in order to perform the calculations required. However when we are using CAST or CONVERT to convert to perform the calculations it is not working.

```
select distinct(ptr.RecordID)
from dbo.PatientRecord as ptr
where
ptr.CHName like 'Access2Loc%'
AND ptr.RecordID
in(
    select
         (
            case when 
                    (DATEDIFF(hour, convert(date,DOB,110), GETDATE())/8766)>18 
                then PatientID
                else NULL
                end
          ) as RecordID 
    from 
    PatientView
    where ISDATE(DOB) = 1
 )
```

Comment: what format is your DOB field in?  (yyyymmdd..)?

Comment: DOB field is a string however the format is mmddyyyy

Comment: `it is not working` - what exactly happens? Error? NULLs? Please give some more details and sample data. Could be you do not have such dates that give `8766 * 19 HOURS` datediff. And that `...IN...SELECT...DATEDIFF...WHERE ISDATE()...` - that all is no good for performance. Also please take note that `IN` does not work well with `NULL`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server considers this a "feature".  It is hard to explain, but the `where` is not necessarily *executed* before the `select`.

In SQL Server 2012+, use `try_convert()` (or `try_cast()`:

```
where ptr.CHName like 'Access2Loc%' and
      ptr.RecordID in (select (case when DATEDIFF(hour, try_convert(date, DOB, 110), GETDATE()) / 8766 > 18 
                                    then PatientID
                               end) as RecordID 
                       from PatientView
                       where ISDATE(DOB) = 1
                      )
```

In more ancient versions, you can use a `case` expression for much the same effect.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. We used try_cast and that does the trick. Accepted your answer. However, if you can , we are trying to get value with decimal points and value. However despite using DECIMAL and float that is not happening. Just asking here so that you can quickly assist us in it otherwise i may have to open a new question.

Comment: @maddysanoo . . . Can you ask another question?

Comment: Sure i can. However Gordon, we ended up using query directly instead of using it through stored procedure. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-- this will guarantee that ##t1 contains only valid dob rows

```
if object_id('tempdb..##t1') is not null
    drop table #t1
select * into ##t1 from patientview where isdate(dob)=1

select distinct(ptr.RecordID)
from dbo.PatientRecord as ptr
where
ptr.CHName like 'Access2Loc%'
AND ptr.RecordID
in(
    select
         (
            case when 
                    (DATEDIFF(hour, convert(date,DOB,110), GETDATE())/8766)>18 
                then PatientID
                else NULL
                end
          ) as RecordID 
    from 
   ##t1
 )
drop table ##t1
```